# Square bracket function in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am learning python. and I dont understand 
     core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
This code. core_sample_mask is array of number 0 to 1499 and I dont understand what squrebracket means in this code, and why = True is followed by.

```
 #data prep, dbscn clustering
 X, y = createDataPoints([[4,3], [2,-1], [-1,4]] , 1500, 0.5)
 epsilon = 0.3
 minimumSamples = 7
 db = DBSCAN(eps=epsilon, min_samples=minimumSamples).fit(X)
 labels = db.labels_
 labels

 #create an array of booleans using the labels from db (I dont       understand what this means..)
 core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
 core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
 core_samples_mask
```

Comment: This is being used for numpy slicing. Check out the [numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) which will help you more with this.

Comment: I know square bracket is used for indexing. But, this one is not covered in my study materials. I have searched for the whole day. And, I could not find the answer. If I was able to find the answer that easily I would have not stated this post.

Answer (score 0):

This is just indexed assignment.  Note which elements of `arr` change:

```
In [374]: mask = np.zeros(6, dtype=bool)                                                  
In [375]: mask                                                                            
Out[375]: array([False, False, False, False, False, False])
In [376]: mask[[1,3,4]] = True                                                            
In [377]: mask                                                                            
Out[377]: array([False,  True, False,  True,  True, False])
```

The same action, but with an integer dtype array:

```
In [378]: arr = np.zeros(6, dtype=int)                                                    
In [379]: arr                                                                             
Out[379]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
In [380]: arr[[1,3,4]] = 1                                                                
In [381]: arr                                                                             
Out[381]: array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0])
```

A similar list assignment:

```
In [382]: alist = [1,2,3,4]                                                               
In [383]: alist[2] = 200                                                                  
In [384]: alist                                                                           
Out[384]: [1, 2, 200, 4]
```

Comment: I suggest you clarify your last statement. Neither of the first two kinds of indexing (using lists of indexes) work with Python lists, lists only accept individual indexes or slices as indexes. Numpy arrays accept more.